# Representing an hierarchy in DAX

Tags: reporting-services, dax

I have a cube that contains a table with the following structure:

```
Level1 | Level2 | Level3 |
  USA        NY   New-York
  USA        NY   Niagra Falls
  USA        WA   Washington
  France  Paris   Montmarte
```

I want to query this so I get the following, using DAX:

```
USA 
   NY
      New-York
      Niagra Falls
   WA
      Washington
France
   Paris
      Montmarte
```

Is this possible to do in one DAX query? Its a representation of the hierarchy.

In the end I want to use this as a filter for an reporting services report, where the user should be able to easy navigate through the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting Services understands hierarchies as represented in the first  example. You can then use a matrix or tablix to represent the hierarchy however you want, including emulating an Excel pivot table, which is what it looks like you're trying to do. [Example.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

While I can think of several ways to represent the hierarchy by using significant whitespace as you've shown in the second example, I will not waste my time or yours, because there is no reporting tool I know of that would be able to make sense of the hierarchy represented in such a format. There is no need to format the hierarchy in the query.

Queries retrieve data. Reporting tools format and display the data prettily. No need to shoehorn reporting tool functionality into a query language.

Edit: I missed the section on using this as a filter.

Reporting Services does not have any native concept of a filter as a report element. Filters are typically implemented as parameters to the report, and you can set up those parameters to follow the hierarchy by making them [cascading parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

If you'd like to have a report element that acts as a filter, then you can emulate slicers with report elements with some wonky workarounds, but it's not fun to implement, so it's time to start asking how much you want to do this in SSRS, or how much you need to have a specific visual implementation of the filter. [Here's a resource on emulating slicers in SSRS](http://www.sqljason.com/2012/07/simulating-slicers-in-ssrs-reports.html).

You could do this based on a matrix, as described above, to represent the hierarchy visually and allow selections within that matrix to reload the report with new selections. It will not be fun. It will be clunky. It will not allow any sort of quick multi-select; i.e. if I want to select 5 items, I will have to go through 5 iterations of clicking on the element and waiting for the report to reload completely. Caching will be your friend.